# How can i remove a specified PushPin integrated with BingMaps?

Tags: tags, pushpin

This is the code, that i made, for adding a pushpin with a specified tag:

```
public void ShowPin()
    {
        Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
        MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, new Location(44.38550, 26.09628));
        pushpin.Tag = "Alex";
        myMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
    }
```

How can i remove the pushpin that have the tag named "x" or "y" ..
Thanks!